# How to explicitly allow clipping?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to clip a column with a container as a way to do an animated transition. However, I am getting the overflow render box error with the yellow caution stripes.

I have tried using ClipRect between the Container whose size is being reduced and its child and I am still running into the same issue.

Is there an ignore all clipping errors widget?

Apologies for the code dump

```
Container(
    height: // varies between 350.0 and 0.0,
    child: Opacity(
      opacity: // varies between 1.0 and 0.0,
      child: ClipRect(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: /* varies between 72.0 and 0.0 */),
            Container(
              height: 224.0,
              child: PageView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  FirstPage(),
                  SecondPage(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            _PageIndicator(index),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: What about removing the SizedBox and wrapping the Column into a Padding instead?

Comment: If I remove the sized box and give the container it's varying padding the layout for some reason gets all jacked up.

Comment: If I remove the sized box and add a container with padding as a child of ClipRect, the problem remains the same.

Comment: I tried removing all SizedBox from this widget and I still can't figure it out. It seems like no matter what I do I cannot clip the column

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Stack, you can put one layer of content(the list) on top of the other layer without it "overflowing".